# Displaying data in a datagrid in an Alfresco task form

Tags: datagrid, workflow, alfresco

I have a json array variable defined in my activity workflow definition. Now, I need to present the data of the json array in a datagrid inside a form task. One of those columns should be a check entry filed so that the user may select some rows. After that, I need to get back that data in a subsequent form task (so I need the data to be updated in the json variable so I can read it back, mainly the user selected checks).

Any example to accomplish this? I didnt find almos nothing relating with using datagrids in Alfresco task forms.

thank you!

Miguel

Comment: Are you looking something like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966639/alfresco-community-5-1-x-workflow-form-add-input-fields-dynamically/37982289#37982289

Comment: similar! thank you!