# Alfresco share how can i create own control of button

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

Alfresco community edition need to create custom own control button field in share
`<Alfresco_HOME>\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfres‌​co\site-webscripts\o‌​rg\alfresco\componen‌​ts\form\controls`

Anyone tell me the how we can create own control.

Comment: Are you expecting something like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966639/alfresco-community-5-1-x-workflow-form-add-input-fields-dynamically/37982289#37982289

Comment: No , In alfresco default feature don't have option to use the button filed so i need to create custom control  button to use

Comment: what is the main use of the button control behaviour? Do you want to submit or open some popup or dialog or something like that?

Comment: button behavior ajax call trigger, button or link whatever how i can use the activiti workflow form , can you help me with reference its more help for this issue

Comment: we need to  build our own control only. We created our own dropdown control to get the data from Alfresco Repo(AJAX request), to update the values in another control. Does this approach will work for you ?

Comment: No, Actually for triggering ajax call create new workflow , if link or button very useful for us, because user going to trigger clicking workflow more than one  for the user perspective we are allowing  5 clicks after user click 5 clicks  button going to disable is this possible? thats why we preferred button or link?

Comment: Once the button / link is disabled , what do you want do with that? You need to store this values somewhere, so that, you can keep the control enabled or disabled in the other user tasks or in workflow history page.

Comment: button / link disabled  after 5 click i will not save anything just user click avoiding,