# insert string array in text box alligned row and column wise in alfresco workflow share form

Tags: html, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

I am setting array of strings(strings dynamic values)in custom property (text box) at alfresco form share.but I need to allign them in proper rows and columns.How to allign dynamic array values in the proper table(inside text box)

//Task Script :- 
**xyz.bpmn**

var stringcollection = "Column1:"+value1+"  "+"  :"+Column2+"value1    "+"End Date: "+stopDate+""................ further concatinated strings. 
execution.setVariable('abc:def', stringcollection);

I need to sort these collection of strings in rows and columns inside text box in task form(workflow alfresco share).

//Share UI visibility with custom size text box. 
**sharecustomconfig.xml**

```
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="abc:taskname">
        <forms>
            <form>
                <field-visibility>

                    <show id="abc:def"/>
                    <show id="packageItems" />
                    <show id="bpm:comment" />
                    </field-visibility>
                <appearance>
                  <field id="abc:def" label="abcdef" read-only="true">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                    <control-param name="style">color: black</control-param>
                    <control-param name="rows">6</control-param>
                    <control-param name="columns">6</control-param>
                    </control>
                  </field>
              </appearance>
        </form>
     </forms>
</config>
```

Comment: Use a custom ftl for a form field to display your data in table format

Comment: Does this helps you  ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37982289/405317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a property in your model file

In your share-config-custom.xml define form field to render

'" field id="your:prop" set="details" label="details" read-only="true" '"

"control template="org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/custom.ftl" "

Define a property which will show your table Define a custom ftl as form field. And pass your variable to this ftl write your logic to sort list of your string in row and column and you can render it in table in your ftl file